# Recaptcha v3 covers the content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

Im using recaptcha v3. However, it covers up the content on my page. It's a icon in down right corner.

[image]

For example, `/` route or `/home` doesnt use recaptcha... so is there a point to keep displaying that icon? In my case, only `/create-user` uses recaptcha. How can I display recaptcha only on this route? Am I allowed to hide it on pages that dont use it?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as long as you include branding. See second FAQ here.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq